# Integer Constants for Substring Lengths

Tags: c#, substring, constants, string-length

I've developed a real antipathy for magic numbers and magic strings. Generally, I create constants with meaningful names and set the values there. This is not an atypical practice. But, I've run into a situation that makes me wonder about my dogma:

I'm writing classes that reflect the components of a standard message string. IOW, a third-party service vendor requires a defined message with "fields" of various lengths. Trying to code defensively, I put string substrings in my gets. For example:

```
        public string BrowserHeader {
        get
        {
            return BrowserHeader.Substring(STRING_START, STRING_MAX);
        }
        set
        {
            BrowserHeader = value;

        }
    }
```

You can see where I used integer constants in the getter. In this case STRING_START = 0, and STRING_MAX = 256. I also have STRING_2, STRING_16, STRING_25, etc. It strikes me, however, that this isn't a good approach. If the vendor changes the length of a given field string, say from 128 to 256, I still have to search the solution for that field to change each instance. The alternative of using BROWSER_HEADER_LENGTH is distasteful because there are scores, if not hundreds, of these fields (and given what I've seen from this vendor, I wouldn't be surprised if they weren't consistent in lengths for a given field).

So, is this a case where integer constants aren't such a bad thing? Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as what you are trying to achieve with your "defensive" programming. BrowserHeader = null, followed by an attempt to read BrowserHeader will result in an exception for example.

Comment: The example that I was thinking of was `MyObject.BrowseHeader = MyObject.BrowseHeader + "HelloWorld!"`

Comment: Dogmas are bad. The names of these constants are horrible -- `STRING_START`? Without context that's as bad as a magic number because it tells you *nothing* about what the value is supposed to model. And this doesn't look like defensive coding but rather like "head-in-the-sand" coding to me. Bad input is not the same as your preconditions being violated. In this case, [fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) by throwing an exception.